# Applying NTFS permissions for groups on a trusted domain

Tags: powershell, cross-domain, acl

I'm trying to write a script to repermission some data on our file servers to add groups from a trusted domain.  At the moment I have:

```
$dc="domaincontroller.organization.com"
creds=get-credential
New-PSDrive -Name TRUSTEDDOM -PSProvider ActiveDirectory -Server $dc -root "//RootDSE/" -Credential $creds
$folder="\\testserver\testshare\testfolder"
$Group = Get-ADgroup -identity "AD_Group" -Server $dc -credential $creds
$acl = Get-ACL -Path $folder
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($group,"FullControl","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow")
$acl.setaccessrule($rule)
set-acl $folder $acl
```

I keep getting

`Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references could not be translated."`

This is my first time trying to work on cross domain permissioning on Powershell so I may be getting something fundamentally wrong.  Is anybody able to assist?

Comment: This can unfortunately be a tricky and frustrating thing to work around. The answer may vary depending on details about the trust, like whether or not it's transitive (two-way) or intransitive (one-way), and whether the domains are in the same forest or if this is a cross-forest trust. Also good to know whether you're running this code within the trusted or trusting forest/domain, and which forest/domain the fileserver belong to.

Comment: It's a two-way trust.  I've decided to use icacls along with the SIDs of the groups on the trusted domain and it seems to be working.  Instead of doing the ACL changes in Powershell I am using Powershell to generate a series of batch files containing the icacls commands which can then be run independently.